# GHDL in Ubuntu 18.040 LTS GTKWAVE VLSI FPGA VHDL

Tags: 18.04, software-installation

Looking Terminal commands to install GHDL and GTK WAVE in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS  Operating System

Error shown below -

```
shivam@shivam-Inspiron-N5010:~$ sudo apt-get install ghdl gtkwave
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ghdl is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

Kindly help me out.

Comment: I looked up `gtkwave` (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=gtkwave) and it's available in 'universe', do you have it enabled?   (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned a quick check of [Ubuntu Package Search](https://packages.ubuntu.com) indicates that `gtkwave` is in the Universe repository. `ghdl` does not currently appear to have a package available in the repositories **for Ubuntu 18.04**. You can however obtain [the code on github](https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl) and roll your own or choose to download a [binary distribution](https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl/releases) or utilize a [docker image](https://github.com/ghdl/docker) to obtain ghdl. If you aren't comfortable with compiling your own, another alternative might be to try utilizing the [script developed by mathieucaroff](https://gist.github.com/mathieucaroff/73ccbd30638d9b37b7129a7b7b8d7726) to Download, Build, And Install ghdl. **Note that I haven't tested the script** but the code is straight forward and looks fine to me. There are also a couple of unsupported and untrusted Personal Archives (PPAs) that provide packages of 'ghdl': mentioned on the [Launchpad Project page.](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ghdl)

Answer (score 1):

Quick search on LaunchPad PPAs - give the [following PPAs](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=ghdl) with `ghdl` package:

- [`ppa:mati75/ghdl`](https://launchpad.net/~mati75/+archive/ubuntu/ghdl?field.series_filter=bionic)

  with version *0.35+dfsg-1~build3*
  and `ghdl`, `ghdl-gcc`, `ghdl-llvm`, `ghdl-mcode`, `update-ghdl-libraries` executables
- [`ppa:gekkio/ghdl`](https://launchpad.net/~gekkio/+archive/ubuntu/ghdl?field.series_filter=bionic)

  with version *0.36-0~gekkio1~bionic1*
  and `ghdl`, `ghdl1-llvm` executables

You can try one of them to install GHDL.

For the `gtkwave` you need to have *universe* pocket enabled.

So the complete solution is as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mati75/ghdl # or ppa:gekkio/ghdl

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gtkwave ghdl*
```

---

When you want to remove PPA with GHDL - use the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:mati75/ghdl # or ppa:gekkio/ghdl
```